# Overriding FilterReader read method in Java

Tags: java, overriding

I am trying to override the read method of FilterReader in Java. My goal is to substitute one run of characters for another. I have accomplished this, but the code fails to stop and eventually the jvm runs out of memory.

Here is my code so far.

```
public class Replacer extends FilterReader {
    /** string to be replaced */
    String find;

    /** string that is inserted in place of string find */
    String replace;

    /** List functioning as a buffer, holds characters 
     * while checking if we have a match */
    LinkedList<Character> buffer;


    /**
     * Constructs a Replacer with the string to be replaced, 
     * find, and the string it is replaced with, replace.
     * 
     * @param find the string to be replaced
     * @param replace the string to replace find with 
     * @param in a Reader Object
     */
    public Replacer(String find, String replace, Reader in) {
        super(in);
        this.find = find;
        this.replace = replace;
        buffer = new LinkedList<Character>();
    }

    @Override
    public int read() throws IOException {
        if (this.buffer.size() > 0) return (int)buffer.poll();

        boolean isMatch = true;
        char x = (char)super.read();

        for (int i=0; i < find.length(); i++) {
            if (x != this.find.charAt(i)) {
                isMatch = false;
                this.buffer.add(x);
                break;
            } else {
                this.buffer.add(x);
            }
            x = (char)super.read();
        }

        if(isMatch) {
            buffer.clear();
            for(int i=0; i < replace.length(); i++) {
                this.buffer.add(replace.charAt(i));
            }
            this.buffer.add(x);
        }
        return (int)buffer.poll();
    }

    @Override
    public int read(char[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
        int result = -1;
        int x = -1;

        for (int i = off; i < len; i++) {
            x = read();
            if (x == -1) {
                result = -1;
                break;
            }
            b[i] = (char)x;
            result++;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Here is the test code to run

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

        URL mun = new URL("http://www.mun.ca/");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new Replacer
                ("head", "balls", new InputStreamReader(mun.openStream())));
        String inputLine;
        while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
            System.out.println(inputLine);
        in.close();
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code needs quite a lot of work.  Start with the `read( char[] ... )` method.  It does not return correct results if an end of stream (-1) is reached in the middle of filling the array.

Comment: Your `read()` also never returns -1

Comment: I wouldn't do it this way. As you're reading lines, I would just do the replacig after reading each line. Much simpler.